# How to measure and create PVT diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, measurements

We have all seen PVT diagrams. From my understanding one should measure pressure, volume and temperature on or near the outside of the system.

- Volume: maybe by displacing water initially and then cameras.
- Temperature: I have some thermometers lying around. But since the system can have different temperatures on different parts of its boundary I don't know how many places I need to measure it.
- Pressure. I don't know how to measure this. Maybe if I hang the system on a hook I can know the pressure at the point it was hung from, but all the other points have me stumped.

Have someone made PVT diagrams and know how it is done?

I found some methods to measure pressure in fluids:

- fiber optical submersible pressure sensor
- pitot tube + manometer
- prandtl tube + manometer

Comment: The idea is to control the pressure, volume and temperature that the system is working in, so you need to control the environment for pressure think of a diving tank used to help divers suffering from bends...

Comment: Then I will try to find some patent about controlling pressure, perhaps that will make me understand.